# New Steam Library Folder must be on a filesystem with execute permissions

Tags: unity, steam, fstab

I've been trying to download civilization 5 on my chromebook through unity. I keep on getting the error message in the title, so I searched and found link such as these: http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864974467574115543 (see second reply) but the problem is I really don't know how to do anything in the terminal or edit the fstab or anything. Exact word for word commands would be very helpful.

edit: I'm trying to download it on a 3.0 16 gb flash drive

Comment: If your goal is to run Civ5, forget it. Please read the hardware requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to download it on a 3.0 16 gb flash drive

- And it is  formatted as NTFS or FAT.Those systems do not support execute permissions.
- Format it as EXT at it will work.
- You can NOT play Windows games over a Windows formatted filesystem through steam in Linux.